# Ubuntu external SSD not booting on my desktop, but works on my laptop

Tags: boot, grub2, partitioning, uefi

I've installed Ubuntu 18.04 successfully onto an external Samsung T5 SSD and it works well with my laptop (ASUS UX303UB: https://www.asus.com/Laptops/ASUS-ZenBook-UX303UB/ ).

However, when I try to boot from the T5 using my desktop, I get this weird black screen where a white [space line type of thing that blinks and moves around a little, but mainly blinks in the upper-left quadrant of the screen.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AT1bE.jpg) Sorry not allowed image embedding yet, but that's a link to a picture I found that looks similar. After a while it just goes into BIOS and I can switch the boot order back to Windows first and everything works fine.

My desktop is a Ryzen machine I built (I know I know, this could already be the reason it doesn't work, but I want to see if it could be something other than Intel vs AMD and different chipsets).

What I tried:

- Disabled fast boot
- Secure boot couldn't be disabled for some weird reason, but it was set to other OS, so it shouldn't be an issue as it's not set for Windows secure boot.
- Went back to the laptop today and the T5 boots nicely.

What I have noticed:

- I'm suspecting this is due to a GRUB issue (or more like my mistake somewhere along the installation), as when I boot into the internal SSD Windows 10 on my laptop, without the T5 connected, GRUB command line shows up and when I type exit it goes away and boots into Windows.
- The GRUB command line shows up on my laptop when the T5 is connected, I type exit and then appears the [GRUB menu where I choose Ubuntu from and it boots nicely.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4X0GQ.png)  The image is not from my PC, so it doesn't have Windows 7 there, I think it just says Windows Boot Manager.

Disk Manager is the other reason I'm suspecting a GRUB related mistake of mine. Here are screenshots from the Windows Disk Manager, first up is [my C: drive on my Windows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IfXxH.png) which has an EFI partition. Here's my T5[which has those weird unallocated spaces and no boot/EFI partition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RQzYu.png). The SSD storage partition (NTFS in the picture) that I created works perfectly on my desktop as well, and it seesUbuntu's partition and swap (I guess that 16GB my swap space?) in disk manager.

But it doesn't boot.

So, did I accidentally install GRUB on my laptop, and if I did, how can I get it to the SSD? Or is it something else entirely.

Comment: If an external drive, you have to install grub to external drive. Big difference if UEFI or BIOS. Both systems really need to both be UEFI or both BIOS. And you will have to manually add boot stanza for Windows as os-prober only finds current system. May be best to see details, use ppa version with your live installer or any working install,  not older Boot-Repair ISO:
Post the link to the Create BootInfo summary report. Is part of Boot-Repair:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info

Comment: Thanks for the comment @oldfred ! I created the Boot-Info summary: http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/6BVnwnMckR/

Line 101 drive sdc looks to be the external SSD in question. Also weirdly enough, when I booted into try Ubuntu I actually saw my 125GB Ubuntu partition on the desktop and was able to access everything, so that's me having screwed up the encrypting bit I was supposed to do... Oh well, at least I know it works.

UEFI on both machines, forgot to mention that and mistakenly called it BIOS out of habit in the question.

Comment: Did you reinstall Windows? You show an UEFI Windows boot in UEFI, but now drives are MBR(msdos) and windows only boots in BIOS mode from MBR drives. Do not run Boot-Repair's auto fix. That may install grub to internal drive & you want Windows boot loader in MBR of internal drive.  Either use Boot-Repair advanced mode and install grub boot loader to MBR of external drive. Shown as sdc, but plugging in flash drive or unplugging it may change order. Always check first. `sudo parted -l` then install grub `sudo grub-install /dev/sdX` where sdX is your drive probably sdc, but always check first.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you oldfred for pointing me in the right direction! Your answer didn't work straight out of the box, but I managed to use Gparted to fiddle around with partitions, creating two 1GB partitions in the beginning of the drive, one exfat32 and one ext4 (EFI and boot drive respectively) and then boot-repair's advanced editor like you suggested and created a boot partition + an EFI partition so now my desktop happily boots into Linux (before it showed Samsung T5 in the boot priority list, now it shows Samsung T5 AND Ubuntu!). Writing this from Ubuntu as a happy man.

And the Windows stuff was due to an old drive I forgot to disconnect, boot-info didn't even recognize my RAID SSDs where my Windows 10 resides.

Comment: If Windows is UEFI and gpt partitioning, generally better to have Ubuntu in same boot mode. And you probably have to add RAID drivers for Ubuntu to see Windows.